# Cannot login to Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome session : amdgpu_device_initialize: DRM version is 2.50.0 but this driver is only compatible with 3.x.x

Tags: drivers, gnome, login, xorg, amdgpu

I am trying to login to my **Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome Session**, But I am get reverted back to the lock screen.

On checking the **Xorg logs** I find this error,

`amdgpu_device_initialize: DRM version is 2.50.0 but this driver is only compatible with 3.x.x.`

Although I am able to login into **Ubuntu Wayland session**.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall amdgpu driver and now login without Wayland. Seems latest amdgpu driver is not compatible with 20.04.

Steps:

1. Reboot.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.
3. Log in.
4. Run: `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`